# How to align coefficients using stargazer in R Markdown?

Tags: r-markdown, stargazer

Every time I add align=TRUE the document won't knit. I would like to align each column's coefficients so that their decimals are directly above/below each other.

Here is my "chunk code"

````
```{r, results="asis", echo="FALSE", eval="TRUE"}
library(stargazer)
stargazer(model1, model2, model3, type = "latex",  
          title = "Country Deaths from Political Violence in 1975",
          dep.var.labels.include = FALSE, dep.var.caption = "Deaths",
          digits = 1, header = FALSE,
          covariate.labels = c("Intercept", "Sanctions", "Political Rights", 
                               "Upper 20 percent income share", 
                               "Interaction of Political Rights and Sanctions"))
```
````

Answer (score 0):

The tex tables produced with `align=TRUE` begin with

```
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} }
```

Applying `gsub` on stargazer and replacing the dots with `\\cdot`. Then using `cat`, solved the problem for me.

MWE:

```
table<-stargazer(example, align=TRUE)
tablenew<-gsub("D{.}{.}{-3} ","D.{\\cdot}{-3}",table,fixed=TRUE)

<<label, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, results='asis', warning=FALSE, message=FALSE>>=
knitrout<-cat(tablenwe, sep="\n")
@
```

One drawback is that `\cdot` is too high.